# Включение и отключение radio кнопок через JS по условию

Tags: javascript, атрибуты, radio

В зависимости от веса заказа в форме активируются разные radio кнопки отвечающие за варианты доставки. Раньше код был через setAttribute и removeAttribute, но некоторое время назад перестал работать. Никак не соображу как исправить. Пробовал так, но ничего не выходит:

```
var weight = document.getElementsByClassName('allweight');
$(function() {
    if(weight > 2) {
        $('delivery_7').removeProp("disabled");
        $('delivery_2').prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else {
        $('delivery_2').removeProp("disabled");
        $('delivery_7').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});

<p>Вес заказа: <span class="allweight">3.3</span> кг</p>
...
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_1" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_2" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_3" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_4" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_5" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_6" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_7" >
```

Comment: delivery_7 != #delivery_7

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  let weight = $('.allweight').text();
  console.log(+weight);
  if(+weight > 2) {
    $('#delivery_7').removeProp("disabled");
    $('#delivery_2').prop("disabled", true);
  }
  else {
    $('#delivery_2').removeProp("disabled");
    $('#delivery_7').prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Вес заказа: <span class="allweight">3</span> кг</p>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_1" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_2" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_3" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_4" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_5" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_6" >
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="1" id="delivery_7" >
```

Comment: Все работает! На сайте была jquery 1.9.2. Не совсем понял, зачем перейти на 2.1.1, но перешел и полет нормальный!